# React dynamic components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I need to load the components dynamically. The list of components is not known in advance. The path to the component will come from the server. How to make the import of components in runtime?

Comment: The `import` statement is static. It only matters at compile time. There is a draft for dynamic `import()` syntax that would make your use case much easier. Check draft progress in here, it is already in stage 3 https://tc39.github.io/proposal-dynamic-import/

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated it explicitly in your question (even though you have tagged it with webpack tag), so I think I can propose this as solution:

Its pretty easy to achieve what you are asking for if you will use module loader (systemjs, requirejs) instead of bundling tools like webpack. They support this kind of functionality out of the box.